# Can I add more Content Views if I had selected an View-based Application Template?

Tags: iphone

I started programming with an View-based Application Template. Now, I figured out that I will need more Content Views (I.e. settings pages, statistics page). I don't really want to make a new project in XCode and struggle around with porting my nib file to that new one since it is pretty complex. I would just want to add that Content Views. Or would that be more work than just making a new project and porting everything into it?

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty easy to add more views to your project. Usually one creates a new nib file containing the new view, and a UIViewController (or a subclass thereof) to go alongside with it.

For modal views you can then use the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method of your current view-controller to show the new view.

Or use a UITabBar to let the user switch between diffrent views.